# Why does MySQL not allow DECIMAL(M,D) with M = D?

Tags: mysql

I can see in [mySQL documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/precision-math-decimal-characteristics.html) that

> D must be no larger than M.

But When I create a database with DECIMAL(10,10), values larger than 1 are inserted as 0.999?
Why can't M be equal to D?

**Edit**: in order to demonstrate:

```
CREATE TABLE `t3` (
 `a` decimal(8,8) NOT NULL
)

INSERT INTO t3 (a) VALUES (1.43);
```

0.99999... wil be inserted.

Comment: Can you demonstrate?

Comment: @Strawberry insert into table (myNum) values (2.43); --> 0.999 will be inserted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've just created a table....

```
CREATE TABLE `t3` (
 `a` decimal(8,8) NOT NULL
)
```

And according to the documentation, this is OK as you point out, D is not larger than M - but it is equal to M.  So that works.

As for why 1 isn't allowed - this is because I've defined a field which has 8 digits - all 8 of which are *after* the decimal place.  As 1 is before the decimal place, it is larger than the range permitted as this is before the decimal place.

Comment: I don't understand what you're saying, I've defined a field with 10 digits for the M and 10 digits for D.

Comment: @wp42 so you've defined a number with 10 digits after the decimal place and only 10 digits in the number, if you want 1 digit before the decimal place, define it as 11,10.

Answer (score 0):

> The declaration syntax for a DECIMAL column is DECIMAL(M,D). The
>   ranges of values for the arguments are as follows:
>
> M is the maximum number of digits (the precision). It has a range of 1
>   to 65. (Older versions of MySQL permitted a range of 1 to 254.)
>
> D is the number of digits to the right of the decimal point (the
>   scale). It has a range of 0 to 30 and must be no larger than M.

[image]

M can't be less than D. or:

> D must be no larger than M.

It's perfectly valid to have M=D. In that case, all of your digits will be to the right of the decimal point, effectively limiting you to store values of 0,00000.... to 0,99999.... where the number of decimal digits is D